# Memory error only when logged in

Tags: php-errors

I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1321273 bytes) in /system/codeigniter/system/core/Loader.php on line 739

but only when logged in to the control panel as a super admin. Any ideas what might be causing that?

Comment: Likely to be an addon, probably specifically an Extension, run amok. What addons are you using?

Comment: CartThrob, Republic Variables, SEO Lite, Freeform, Stash, EE Debug Toolbar, Matrix. I guess it's something to do with CartThrob as it only happens on pages in the /shop/ template group. But when would it only happen when logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at line 739 in Loader.php. It's `$buffer = ob_get_contents();`. Here is the code right around it.

```
log_message('debug', 'File loaded: '.$_ci_path);

// Return the file data if requested
if ($_ci_return === TRUE)
{
    $buffer = ob_get_contents();
    @ob_end_clean();
    return $buffer;
}
```

Looks like a debug message is being logged right before this line which will help you track this backwards.

Here's details on [**enabling logging in EE config.php**](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/191514/#903988).

You could also add an additional debug message inside the conditional. Something like:

```
log_message('debug', 'Buffer data: '.$buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks Anna. Turns out it was the EE Debug Toolbar extension which was causing the error so I've disabled it.

Comment: You should tell Eric Lamb about that, i'm sure he'd be interested in the bug report!